# Page is not indexed: Duplicate without user-selected canonical

Tags: indexing, single-page-application, google-search-console

I have pages that have not changed for sure for the last year. In Google Search Console I see that many of my pages are removed from indexation.

[image with an indexing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stALp.png)

The main reason is Duplicate without user-selected canonical but my content is totally different on every page.  I will give one example:

This site:
https://rejsy4you.pl/armatorzy/msc-cruises%5C

is a duplicate of this:
https://rejsy4you.pl/statek/costa-firenze%5C

[example image from GSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG89A.png)

Those sites are totally different with different content. One important fact is that this site is written in angular as SPA (Single Page Application) and I know that pages with JavaScript are more problematic, but why now? Everything was OK for such a long time!

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?